# Failed to create an object instance for the specified ProgID (WIA.CommonDialog)

Tags: silverlight, wia

We are trying to allow users to scan documents using a Silverlight XAP running in-browser with elevated trust, from a remote server, and are getting the following error:

> Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Failed to create an object instance for the specified ProgID.

The failure is at the following line:

```
Dim CommonDialog = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog")
```

**Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions** and **AutomationFactory.IsAvailable** both return True.

I can successfully create an instance of unsafe ActiveX controls, e.g. `Scripting.FileSystemObject`:

```
Dim fso = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

The code fails when running from the production environment on the remote server. When running from the ASP.NET Development server from localhost, the code succeeds, and the WIA scanning dialog is shown when calling `CommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage()`.

How can I resolve this? (Is there perhaps something specific about WIA that prevents it from being used this way?) What steps can I take to try and debug this?

**Update**

When I try to open the generated Silverlight test page (via the `file` protocol), I get the same error.

**Update 2**

Process Monitor shows that the `AllowLaunchOfElevatedTrustApps` and `AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser` keys are being successfully queried.

**Update 3**

With Protected Mode turned off, the code works.

Comment: When you run the code out of a xap (ie: in a regular c# console app for example), does it work? Also, have you checked out this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2013/07/17/what-are-required-for-silverlight-application-that-requires-elevated-trust.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier As I mentioned in my post, when I run it off `localhost` using the VS development server, the code works. This class exists only in the Silverlight runtime, and I cannot seem to access it from other project types even when I add a reference. RE: the link you mentioned, I've already carried out all the steps listed in that post, and I get a different error message (the error message described in the link is **This operation is not supported in the current context.**). It doesn't seem to be a permissions error, otherwise `Scripting.FileSystemObject` would fail in the same way.

Comment: The non-silverlight C# equivalent is this `var dlg = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WIA.CommonDialog"));`. Please try it. Otherwise you must do as what's described in the post. Don't compare with other COM objects just with a simple test. Two COM objects can be very different. For example, FileSystemObject does not display any UI, while CommonDialog does.

Comment: @SimonMourier It does work in a console application.

Comment: Silverlight is a client-side application, whether it is served from production or development server should have been immaterial. You can debug/attach to Silverlight application served from Production using Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you done what's described in the post?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes I have, as I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I mean the post to the msdn article

Comment: @SimonMourier Do you mean https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=VS.95).aspx ? I've already enabled the registry key, installed a valid certificate, and signed the XAP with that certificate.

Comment: I meant this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2013/07/17/what-are-required-for-silverlight-application-that-requires-elevated-trust.aspx (can't you just read past comments?)

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes (as I mentioned in my first comment -- _I've already carried out all the steps listed in that post_ -- so I thought you might have meant the MSDN link referenced within the blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) states that to enable COM Interop inside the browser, you must

1. Set Registry Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\` (or on x64 `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight\`)  **AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser** `DWORD` `0x0000001`
2. Check your group policy has not disabled `AllowInstallOfElevatedTrustApps` and `AllowLaunchOfElevatedTrustApps`
3. Sign the .xap
4. Install cert to Trusted Application Store (see [screenshots](http://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications) illustrating how)

Additionally, you must

1. configure as Out of Browser Application (even if you are not running Out of Browser)
2. before calling the `ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject` you should check for [`Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.haselevatedpermissions(v=vs.95).aspx) and `AutomationFactory.IsAvailable`
3. note that Elevated Permission testing from http://localhost and http://127.0.0.1 is not reliable test, as Silverlight runtime makes exception for these two URLs. Instead use `file://`.

Troubleshooting

1. Use ProcMon to verify that the `AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser` registry key is being read
2. Attach Debugger to Silverlight (see [screenshots](https://joeknowsdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/attaching-visual-studios-debugger-to-silverlight-applications/))
3. MSIE Protected Mode settings can also adversely affect whether a Silverlight application can run with Elevated Permissions. Try running with different Protected Mode settings.