# Failed to create an object instance for the specified ProgID (Outlook.Application)

Tags: silverlight, outlook, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to automate Outlook email creation from Silverlight app. Here is code I have:

```
dynamic fso = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
dynamic cd = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog");
dynamic outlook = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Outlook.Application");
```

Third line fails with error in subject. I found similar post:
[Failed to create an object instance for the specified ProgID (WIA.CommonDialog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642662/failed-to-create-an-object-instance-for-the-specified-progid-wia-commondialog)

So, I do have some other elevated permission functionality and it is all working. On purpose I tried to add 2 lines of code (first 2 lines) which author of above linked post had problems with. Now, it looks like issue not with my config but with Outlook itself.

Is it possible that Outlook 2013 I have does not "respond" to "Outlook.Application" name?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is a singleton, so the COM system will attempt to connect to the running instance. If the security contexts of Outlook and your app are different, COM will not marshal the existing object.

Where does your code run?

Comment: Right now I'm just running it locally on my IIS. It's SL app with elevated permissions. Outlook is open and running

Comment: IIS is a service, and Outlook (or any other Office app) cannot be used from a service.

Comment: I'm using it from Silverlight client, not from server.

Comment: If you are still getting an error, that means the  security contexts are different. What does your code do? If using Redemption is an option, its RDO family of objects is loaded in-proc and can access Outlook data.

Comment: It's a Silverlight client, registering another COM object on client PC is not really an option.. It works, kind of, now. On my 2013 line of code will execute if Outlook closed at the moment. With 2010 on other machines it seems to work fine. So, issue was with my Outlook and it's documented elsewere on Internet with 2013

Comment: This is not Outlook specific behavior, this is how COM marshaling works.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just running it locally on my IIS.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

Comment: Quoted text relates to how I run app for development. Silverlight is a client technology. I'm trying to automate LOCAL outlook similar to "mailto:" in html. I'm not running outlook on server, it's on my client's machine

Answer (score 0):

With Outlook 2013 Automation does not work if Outlook open. If I close outlook - this works.