# Failed to create object "Scripting.FileSystemObject" with SilverLight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have the silverlight app, which uploads a folder selected by client to the server, with all nested files and folders, preserving inner structure.

To access file system app creates `Scripting.FileSystemObject` object with `AutomationFactory.CreateObject` method.

When app run inside the browser, `AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` raises error "not supported in current context".

When app run outside of the browser, everything works fine.

With silverlight 4 there was no such error even if app run inside the browser.

How can I solve this error with silverlight 5? Is there other way to upload from the browser to the server selected folder with all subfolders and files?

It must work in IE (10+ or edge - any of this).

The app is for corporate intranet. Any browser settings and policies can be applied.

I have seen answer to this question: [Failed to create an object instance for the specified ProgID (WIA.CommonDialog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642662/failed-to-create-an-object-instance-for-the-specified-progid-wia-commondialog)
Everything was done and worked for silverlight 4 but not for 5.

Comment: Side note, it might be worth considering an alternate solution given microsoft announced end of life for silverlight 4 years ago (patches and bugfixes until 2021).

Comment: @Takarii I cannot find any solution to load folders in IE.

Comment: What back end are you using? IE is just a browser and has little to no bearing on the ability to upload folders.

Comment: Unless you run from a local disk drive you're not allowed to access files or folders directly from the browser context, and this limitation is upheld inside Silverlight. You're only allowed to access files in an upload context. And yes, there are ways to upload folders but I have no idea how to implement them, I just know that the webinterface for Google Drive allows you to drop in a folder, and it'll all be uploaded.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In IE Google Drive displays: `Folder upload is not supported by your browser. Consider downloading Chrome.`

Comment: @Takarii what the difference what the backend is if you cannot send data on frontend?

Comment: Then you can't do it. For security reasons you're not allowed to directly access the local file system.